# Using iterator inside a method with ArrayList

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me if what this method mean?

```
 clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();

 public void tellEveryone(String message) {
     Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
     while(it.hasNext()) {
         try {
             PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
             writer.println(message);
             writer.flush();
         } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
     }//end while
 }//end method
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific and while being specific try to indent your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be implementing an [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern where subscribers are the output streams targets.

That is, you have a list of output streams where the message is going to be published whenever someone calls to `tellEveryone` method. Having the output streams references stored in a list allows to easily add "listeners", in this case, output channels without changing your code.

This is your code commented:

```
clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList(); //Subscribers list
...
...
 public void tellEveryone(String message) {  //Publish your message writing it in each single outPutStream
     Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator(); //Get an iterator to traverse the subscriber list
     while(it.hasNext()) { 
         try {
             PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
             writer.println(message); //Print the message.
             writer.flush();
         } catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();} //Catch any posssible exception, (what happens if one stream is closed?)
     }//end while
 }//end method
```

An example of use could be a log for which you want the messages to be sent through a socket connection as well as to be stored in a file. To perform that task you just have to add the socket's `PrintWriter` object and your file's `PrintWriter` to `clientOutputStream` once. 
Then, whenever a message is to be logged you just have to call to `tellEveryone` and it will be stored in the file and sent to the connection receiver.

Answer (score -1):

This method seems to output the "clientOutputStreams" to the "message", and turned the ASCII code into the default character set. The iterator, in my view, it looks like a poniter, points to the element of the array.